# UILabel Character spacing to include background and underline attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am wanting a `UILabel` where each character is underlined and has a background, while also having a space between the background of each individual character - so essentially each character is in it's own "box"

I have tried using `attributedText` on a `UILabel` but having set the `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` and `NSKernAttributeName` the background fills the entire label, essentially I'd like a gap of clear color between each letter.

Is there a way of doing this with attributed text, or will this need to be resolved with another solution?

I currently have tried the following as an example:

```
NSMutableAttributedString* string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"EXAMPLE"];
[string addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)]
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)]
[string addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName value:@(5) range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
[label setAttributedText:string];
```

Current result:
[image]

Desired Result:
[image: desired result with spaces between letters]

(you can ignore the colors, this is just an example)

Comment: Update your question with the code you have tried. Show the result you are getting and show the result you wish to get.

Comment: Thanks, @rmaddy I've updated my question

Comment: You are setting the colors for the whole string. One option would be to put spaces between each letter and set the colors (at least the background) for each individual letter.

Comment: Ideally I'd need another way without adding spaces between each character, I've been wondering if there was an option to override - (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect and add a background or frame to each letter individually but to no avail.

Comment: Are you planning on interacting with each letter independently?

Comment: The letters will start unfilled (so perhaps with an underscore in the place of a letter) and then are filled in as the user types.

Comment: Could you find any answer? I have excatly same problem